# Google Kickstart 2020 Round A allocation problem in c

Tags: c, sorting

I have wrote the code in C language but it seems to pass the sample cases but when it comes to test cases it shows wrong answer.
Input
The first line of the input gives the number of test cases, T. T test cases follow. Each test case begins with a single line containing the two integers N and B. The second line contains N integers. The i-th integer is Ai, the cost of the i-th house.

Output
For each test case, output one line containing Case #x: y, where x is the test case number (starting from 1) and y is the maximum number of houses you can buy.

Limits
Time limit: 15 seconds per test set.
Memory limit: 1GB.
1 ≤ T ≤ 100.
1 ≤ B ≤ 105.
1 ≤ Ai ≤ 1000, for all i.
Test set 1
1 ≤ N ≤ 100.
Test set 2
1 ≤ N ≤ 105.
Sample

Input

Output

3
4 100
20 90 40 90
4 50
30 30 10 10
3 300
999 999 999

Case #1: 2
Case #2: 3
Case #3: 0

In Sample Case #1, you have a budget of 100 dollars. You can buy the 1st and 3rd houses for 20 + 40 = 60 dollars.
In Sample Case #2, you have a budget of 50 dollars. You can buy the 1st, 3rd and 4th houses for 30 + 10 + 10 = 50 dollars.
In Sample Case #3, you have a budget of 300 dollars. You cannot buy any houses (so the answer is 0).

And My code is

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int test;
    scanf("%d",&test);
    for(int i=1;i<=test;i++){
        int N;
        long int B;
        scanf("%d %ld",&N,&B);
        long int Case = 0,r=0;
        int array[10000];
        char ch;
        do {
            scanf("%d%c",&array[r],&ch);
            r++;
        }while(ch!='\n');
        for (int k=0;k<N;k++){
            for (int m=k;m<N;m++){
                int temp;
                if(array[k]>array[m]){
                    temp=array[k];
                    array[k]=array[m];
                    array[m]=temp;
                }
            }
        }
        r=0;
        while(Case<=B){
            Case+=array[r];
            r++;
        }
        printf("Case #%d: %d\n",i,r-1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Since google hosts these questions online, a link to the question on google's site near the top of your question body would be nice.  It would save me doing a web search and then guessing which result will get me the exact version you are looking at.

Comment: Which test-case has your first error?  Is it small sample, large sample etc?  Also, keep in mind your first sentence / paragraph should be a brief verbal summary with little to no actual details.  That helps us set our minds to the problem at hand before we dive into the nitty gritty.

Comment: It would be great if your code had comments explaining your reasoning / plan of action as you go along.  Also, since it is failing, you should have some analysis of what you think *might* be wrong.  Even if your analysis ends in 3 completely random and unrelated guesses, it shows effort you've put into solving this yourself and saves us the effort of retracing those steps.

Comment: At a bare minimum your comments and formatting should show us where the "template code" that is the same for every solution to every google challenge breaks off from the "problem solution" that is unique to only this particular challenge.  I shouldn't have to read every line of your software to find that when you can just point it out.

Comment: Finally... It looks like your output loop: `while(Case<=B){` has unintended consequences which would make any solution only acceptable out of pure luck.  Also note: It's a good idea to "eyeball" or manually read the text file containing your answers to see if it is as expected.  I'd wager that in the larger files you don't have the correct number of sequential answer statements let alone correct answer values.

Answer (score 0):

The main culprit is the condition controlling the `while` loop below

```
while(Case<=B){ /* the logic of condition expression is wrong*/
   Case+=array[r];
   r++;
}
```

It must have been `(r < N && Case+array[r]<=B)` (`r<N` is necessary; you must also check the array index). The line

```
printf("Case #%d: %d\n",i,r-1);
```

is also wrong. It must be corrected as

```
printf("Case #%d: %ld\n",i,r);
```

Another mistake is the array size in `int array[10000];`. The size must have been `100000` since the value of `N` can be `100000` at maximum.

Your sorting algorithm is slow. A faster algorithm or the standard library function `qsort` should have been used.